# How can I tell if I have permission to run a particular command?

Tags: command-line, permissions

Is there any way to identify whether I as an ordinary user have the right to issue a command.

For example; I want to check whether I have right to issue the *shutdown* command before I actually issue it.

Something like the following commands

```
-> doIhaveRightToIssue shutdown
-> Yes/No
```

Comment: The straight-forward way is to try (without `sudo`) and find out. Text mode commands may need `sudo` and graphical commands may need `gksudo`. You can also check where the command is installed with `which command`. If in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` - you can expect that the command needs `sudo` or `gksudo`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simplest case is that of a binary executable like `gzip`. First, we locate the executable:

```
$ which gzip
/bin/gzip
```

Then we look at the attributes of this file:

```
$ ls -l /bin/gzip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 98240 oct 27  2014 /bin/gzip
```

The three x's tell us that the file may be executed by the owner (the first `root`), or anyone in the group `root` (second `root`) and anyone else, respectively. So your user is allowed to execute the program.

However, your executable may be a script file that calls other executables inside. You may be able to execute the script but not the programs called inside of it. There is no way to determine if your user is allowed to do that, other than actually trying it out.

Then there are special cases like `shutdown` - this is really a symbolic link to a core utility called `systemctl`, which has its own mechanisms to determine whether you are allowed to call it, and to ask you for your sudo password if you don't, for instance.

(About the `which` command: this locates executables in your $PATH that you are allowed to execute, and tells you which one you use if you have more than one with the same name in the $PATH. It does not locate just any executable. I use it here as an example of where to look for the permission. The fact that `which` finds the executable already indicates that you have permission to execute it.)

Comment: Very concise answer (+1). For example, it is possible to simulate the result of apt-get install with -s flag (sudo apt-get install -s htop). I have thought if there is no way to learn the permission of a command before one issues, there is at least something like "simulate".

Comment: Certainly, there are utilities that provide a "dry-run" or "simulate" flag that you can use.

Comment: `which` command should be sufficient for those files that reside in one of the directories added to `$PATH` variable. For instance , doing `sudo chmod 700 /bin/nano` or `sudo chmod 744 nano` causes `which` to produce no output.  For local scripts, that reside somewhere other than one of `PATH` directories, `ls -l` or `stat` calls will do the trick. Good answer, but please add this info to your post

Comment: Going off what Serg said, use something like `stat -c '%a' /bin/gzip` to get `755` for example.

Answer (score 22):

With `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -l shutdown
/sbin/shutdown
```

If I didn't have permission, `sudo` will complain instead of showing the command.

With polkit, you check for the action you want to run:

```
$ pkcheck --action-id org.freedesktop.login1.power-off --process $$ -u --enable-internal-agent && echo yes
polkit\56temporary_authorization_id=tmpauthz1
yes
```

Finding the relevant action is a different question.

Comment: The problem with sudo is that I am not sudoer in the system. Because of that, I try to be careful before I really issue a command.

Comment: @BernhardColby you can safely run `sudo -l` even if you're not a sudoer - that's the whole point of `-l` - to tell you whether you can run a command with sudo.

Comment: Thanks (+1), i did not know it. I will try your solution as soon as i got my pc.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
test -x $(command -v shutdown) && echo yes || echo no
```

`command -v shutdown` returns the path to the `shutdown` command. `test -x` checks if that path is executable to you.

Note that though you might be able to execute the command, the command may still fail because it has inadequate permission to carry out the task. This is the common case on Unix-type systems, which rather than restricting access to execute a command, instead restrict access on the operations that programs can actually do.

Comment: What about e.g. `alias shutdown="shutdown now"`?

Comment: To avoid the issue with aliases one can use `$(which shutdown)` or `$(shopt -u expand_aliases && command -v shutdown)`. This issue only appears in interactive mode though.

Answer (score 5):

Well it can be a bit difficult at times...

First of all, look at the permissions with `ls -l`...

```
 owngrpotr  user  group  command
-rwxr-xr-x  root  bin    vim
```

If the last/third triplet got an **x** ("can execute") in it, then *others* - and that means you - can execute it...  If it's a shell-script or something like that, then *others* would need **r** ("can read") too.

If *others* don't got execute-permission but *group* (the second triplet) does, then you can execute it if you're a member of the *group* - in the example over, *bin*.  For example, the *wheel*-group is often used to limit who may run `su`, so only users belonging to this group could execute it at all.  Another example is making a group for *develop*ers, and restrict execution of the C-compiler and such tools to this group.

If there is a trailing **+** after the last triplet, that means that AccessControllLists are used - this may add execution-rights to additional users and groups.

+++

Even if you are able to execute the command, the command may depend on access to files, directories and/or devices that you don't have access to - this may limit what you'll be able to do (you may not be able to do anything).

Finally although you may be allowed to execute a command, the command itself may check your identity, and refuse to let you use it unless you're  listed in a config-file or is certain users (eg. *root*).  For example the `mount` command will only allow *root* to mount any device - normal users are only allowed to mount devices listed as such in /etc/fstab... which may be none.  If you're not *root* and tries to mount something, `mount` will complain and refuse to mount the device.  Another example is `sudo`, which will run for anybody, but only users listed in /etc/sudoers will actually be allowed to run things as *root*.

Answer (score 3):

Using `which`, `type`, `command` etc. is a practical solution which will work in 99% of the cases, but to be 100% sure you'll have to manually inspect every executable directory listed in your `$PATH`. Many shells (including `bash`) will prefix your command with entres from `$PATH` and try to execute those files repeatedly until they succeed. Since `which` cannot really execute the command, it's impossible for it to predict which file your shell will really pick.

For example, imagine I have `PATH=/opt/arm/bin:/bin`, both directories containing executable files, but for different architectures. Running `which dd` will return `/opt/arm/bin/dd` (assuming I have permissions to execute it), since that entry comes first. However, when I run `dd` in my shell, `/bin/dd` will be executed, because `/opt/arm/bin/dd` will fail to run. The same situation may happen in case of corrupt binaries, missing libs, etc. In the end, there's no sure way to know whether you will be able to execute a command or not, aside from trying.

Another aspect is what you consider "having permissions". As a user, I do have permissions to run `rm ~/file` but not `rm /root/file`. Again, there's no general way to know that without manual inspection, or issuing the command and observing the results.